# How to add a Jar dependancy to a Java Google App Engine project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant, intellij-idea

I am trying to learn how to use GAE, I want to use gson in my project.

I am using intellij and building using ant (because intellij does not seem to like building the GAE project).  I have build successfully already, but now I want to use gson. Intellij recognises the imports, but when I try to build I get the following error from ant:

"error: package com.google.gson does not exist"

I Googled this problem and advice says to put the jar into WEB-INF/lib which I have done.  But I still get the error. I also tried using a maven dependancy instead, but faced the same issues.

I am using the ant build script provided in the sdk/demos/template. Maybe I need to change something in there?

EDIT
I managed to get it working in the end, the ant file wasn't including the WEB-INF build folder.  Here is the new compile task in ant, I hope it helps someone :)

```
<target name="compile"
      description="Compile the application servlet code">
<mkdir dir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
<mkdir dir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
  <classpath>
    <fileset dir="${appengine.sdk}/lib/user">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${appengine.sdk}/lib/shared">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
      <fileset dir="src/WEB-INF/lib">
          <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
  </classpath>
</javac>
<copy todir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/lib"
      flatten="true">
  <fileset dir="${appengine.sdk}/lib/user">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
  </fileset>
    <fileset dir="src/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: yes, I cleaned and tried to compile.  I'm using ant to build, so ant clean, ant compile or ant runserver

Comment: I'm just reading the ant build script, and I can't see it doing anything with WEB-INF/lib

Comment: The error isn't intellij based, I'm using ant to build via commandline

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add WEB_INF/lib to your build path as [specified by the doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant?hl=fr).

```
<path id="project.classpath">
    <pathelement path="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${sdk.dir}/lib">
      <include name="shared/**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </path>
```

If you aren't totally attached to Intellij, I've had really good luck using the [Eclipse plugin for GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse). (I know; switching IDE"S...)

Comment: Hi, that didn't work but it got me on the right track

Answer (score 2):

What you've done is a bit of a hack. Ideally, you should do the following:

- Create a thirdparty dir next to (not in) your war dir. There should not be a need to have a duplicate WEB-INF dir in src/WEB-INF/lib.
- Add your Gson.jar to that dir and source control it from here.
- Open Project Structure->Libraries->New Project Library->From Java
- Select your jar (or the thirdparty dir itself may work).
- Go to Modules->Dependencies->Add Library and select your new library
- Go to Artifacts->Output Layout
- If your library is not already in the right pane, do Add Library Files and select your new library
- You should be able to just double click this library in the right pane
- This should result in the library showing up in the left pane as "`<library name>` (Project Library)" under WEB-INF/lib/

Also verify that

- Your Artifacts->Output Layout->Type is Web Application: Exploded
- Your Artifacts->Output Layout->Output Directory is your war dir
- Project->Compiler Output is your /war/WEB-INF/classes dir

Doing this should cause IntelliJ to move the Gson.jar to the WEB-INF/lib dir when building. It should also allow you to build your project in IntelliJ without needing to run ant outside of the IDE. Let me know if you have any questions or need additional help. I've been fighting these issues for the last few months.